# How to transfer data via DMA from RAM to RAM?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, dma

I want to write a kernel module that can transfer data via DMA from RAM to RAM. There are some posts that discuss this, but I don't really get it. Some say it is possible others say it isn’t.

If I understood ldd3 right, RAM to RAM copying isn‘t possible with the DMA API of linux, but the *driver/dma/dmaengine.c*  provides a flag DMA_MEMCPY for a "DMA Transfer Type", so there should be a way.

Is this correct, can I use a dma engine to transfer data from one ram address to another?

If it is hardware dependent, how can I determine if my system supports dma memcpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you correctly pointed out, `DMA_MEMCPY` should be used to perform RAM-to-RAM copy. It is described in [Documentation/dmaengine/provider.txt](https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/dmaengine/provider.html#supported-transaction-types). Here is just a related excerpt, please see the whole file for more details:

> ### Supported transaction types

> The next thing you need is to set which transaction types your device
> (and driver) supports.

> Our `dma_device` structure has a field called `cap_mask` that holds the
> various types of transaction supported, and you need to modify this
> mask using the `dma_cap_set` function, with various flags depending on
> transaction types you support as an argument.

> All those capabilities are defined in the `dma_transaction_type` enum,
> in `include/linux/dmaengine.h`

> Currently, the types available are:

> - `DMA_MEMCPY`
>
>   - The device is able to do memory to memory copies

Just to summarize:

- It depends on your DMA controller. Some are able to do RAM-to-RAM transaction, some aren't.
- For example, for OMAP-based SoCs, DMA controller does this (`drivers/dma/omap-dma.c` file, in `omap_dma_probe()` function):

  ```c
   dma_cap_set(DMA_MEMCPY, od->ddev.cap_mask);
  ```
- This way you can later check it (if your DMA controller is capable of RAM-to-RAM transactions) in your driver. See how it's done in `drivers/dma/dmatest.c`, in `dmatest_add_channel()` function:

  ```c
   if (dma_has_cap(DMA_MEMCPY, dma_dev->cap_mask)) {
  ```

If you need an example on how to use DMA API to perform RAM-to-RAM transaction, please see [drivers/dma/dmatest.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/dma/dmatest.c).

Comment: I would add couple of things, i.e. a) if DMA_PRIVATE is not set by the driver the memcpy can be backed by DMA in general, b) *drivers/dma/dmatest.c* would be an example how to do this.

Comment: The links are broken