# Linux SRAM to RAM DMA transfer

Tags: linux-kernel, beagleboneblack, dma

I'm using the linux 4.1 kernel on a beaglebone black. I want to do a DMA transfer from a SRAM (FPGA connected through the GPMC) and normal RAM. How would I do this? I see a lot of documentation for device to memory or memory to device but not much on memory to memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766230/how-to-transfer-data-via-dma-from-ram-to-ram/37768383#37768383

Comment: @SamProtsenko it depends how SRAM is addressed. If it occupies the same amount of CPU address space, then mem-2-mem transfers are okay, otherwise one has to use a differrent approach.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko Yeah, I'm aware of that. Good point, though. Some time ago I was working with GPMC IP-core in OMAP-based TI SoC, so I know that it's mapped into main address space. Look at [AM335x SoC TRM](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruh73m/spruh73m.pdf), section 2.1, it specifies addresses from 0x0000_0000 to 0x1fff_ffff for GPMC memory. So the DMA copy from RAM to RAM should work fine in this case.

Comment: Yeah, looking into it some more it looks like a RAM to RAM transfer will work. However, I haven't connected the GPMC device yet nor have I configured the kernel either. How can I be sure that my kernel module is the only thing allowed to access the SRAM interface?

Comment: @CalebMerchant I think you really should ask it as another question.