# DMA transaction requires copying into buffer every time?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dma

It might be a silly question, but I haven't got it so far about DMA.
When doing memory to memory DMAing, it requires to allocate DMA buffer
(for example with `dma_alloc_coherent()`), then for each transfer we need to copy the buffer to the allocated memory (source buffer) and then trigger DMA transaction.

So, if it requires additional `memcpy()` for each transaction, what's the
benefit of using DMA?

Steps for copying source to destination - **without DMA**:

1. copy buffer (`memcpy()`) from source to destination

Steps for copying source to destination - **with DMA**:

1. copy buffer (`memcpy()`) from source to DMA buffer
2. trigger DMA transaction (which shall copy the buffer eventually to
   destination buffer)

An example of this problem is with Ethernet driver, which need to copy from the recieved `sk_buf` into physical address of FPGA. In this case it shall requires copying the `sk_buf` into the DMA source buffer (from `dma_alloc_coherent()`) first.

Comment: Which exactly driver are you talking about? Can you show us some actual code **in mainline kernel** where you see the problem?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to find simple example in kernel. I am writing my own ethernet driver, and I am not sure that using dma is effective - just as I wrote. If there is any mistake in my questions or assumption, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use `dma_map_single()` with the `sk_buf` pointer, then you do not have to copy it into a buffer allocated with `dma_alloc_coherent()`. There are many examples of this in network device drivers.

```c
int dma_len = skb->len;
dma_addr_t dma_addr = dma_map_single(dev, skb->data, skb->len, DMA_TO_DEVICE);

// error checking code here
// then send the dma_addr to the drvice
// when it is done, unmap it
dma_unmap_single(dev, dma_addr, dma_len, DMA_TO_DEVICE);
```

See the [DMA Mapping API documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt) for more details.

Comment: but I am using memory to memory (the fpga space is mapped), so I am not sure I should use DMA_TO_DEVICE ? I did read  DMA Mapping API documentation, but it did not make clear when it should be memory-to-memory and when memory-to/from-device

Comment: *memory-to-memory* happens only when you use memory on both sides (with **incremental** addresses and corresponding bus width. In case of **fixed** address of the FIFO you have to use *memory-to-device* and *device-to-memory* transfers.

Comment: It is a icremented address. how do I specify that it is memory-to-memory ?

Comment: @ransh FYI: [How to transfer data via DMA from RAM to RAM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766230/how-to-transfer-data-via-dma-from-ram-to-ram)

Comment: If your processor chipset does not support DMA from memory to memory, I suggest adding a DMA controller to your FPGA so that it can read from the host memory. I assumed that was the case you were describing in your question because you asked about network interfaces, which use DMA to read from host memory.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my answer is no longer relevant to the post owner, but maybe it would help some other programmers in the future.

As mentioned in one of the comments here, if your FPGA have a DMA controller (which allows the FPGA to read the memory that has been mapped to the DMA), then you should be able to do DMA without `memcpy()` operations.

I will try to give here a short (as possible...) example of how it can be implemented in an Ethernet driver in the Rx flow (but there are more than one method of how to implement it and this is only a general example to understand the basic steps and concept). Please note that I've tried to simplify it, so do not try to compile it (this is not the full code - for a full Ethernet driver review, you can try start looking on [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.152/source/drivers/net/ethernet/stmicro/stmmac/stmmac_main.c) driver).

Now, let's focus on these basic steps:

- Initialize the Rx Buffers
- Rx Frame Reception
- Prepare the Rx buffers for the next DMA transactions
- Free the Rx Buffers

**Initialize the Rx Buffers**

```
static int init_dma_rx_desc_rings(struct net_device *dev, gfp_t flags)
{
    struct my_private *tp = (struct my_private *)dev->priv;

    int ret = -ENOMEM;
    int i;

    tp->dma_buf_sz = BUF_SIZE_16KiB;

    for (i = 0; i < DMA_RX_SIZE; i++) {
        ret = init_rx_buffers(dev, i, flags);
        if (ret)
            goto err_init_rx_buffers;
    }

    return 0;

err_init_rx_buffers:
    for (i = 0; i < DMA_RX_SIZE; i++) {
        ret = free_rx_buffer(dev, i);
        if (ret)
            goto err_init_rx_buffers;
    }

    return ret;
}

static int init_rx_buffers(struct net_device *dev, int i, gfp_t flags)
{
    struct my_private *tp = (struct my_private *)dev->priv;
    struct sk_buff *skb = __netdev_alloc_skb_ip_align(dev, tp->dma_buf_sz, flags);

    if (!skb) {
        printk("Rx init fails; skb is NULL\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    tp->rx_skbuff[i] = skb;
    tp->rx_skbuff_dma[i] = dma_map_single(tp->device, skb->data,
                                          tp->dma_buf_sz, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);

    if (dma_mapping_error(tp->device, tp->rx_skbuff_dma[i])) {
        printk("DMA mapping error\n");
        dev_kfree_skb_any(skb);
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Rx Frame Reception**

```
/* should be called by the interrupt handler or NAPI poll method*/
static void receive_packets(struct net_device *dev)
{
    struct my_private *tp = (struct my_private *)dev->priv;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    int rx_work_limit = tp->dirty_rx + RX_RING_SIZE - tp->cur_rx;
    unsigned int next_entry = tp->cur_rx;

    while (count < rx_work_limit) {
        int entry = next_entry;

        /* read the status of the incoming frame */
        int status = get_rx_status(tp);

        /* check if managed by the DMA otherwise go ahead */
        if (unlikely(status & dma_own))
            break;

        count++;
        tp->cur_rx = get_rx_entry(tp->cur_rx, DMA_RX_SIZE);
        next_entry = tp->cur_rx;

        /*  If frame length is greater than skb buffer size
            (preallocated during init) then the packet is ignored */
        int frame_len = get_rx_frame_len(tp);   
        if (frame_len > tp->dma_buf_sz) {
            printk("len %d larger than size (%d)\n", frame_len, tp->dma_buf_sz);    
            continue;
        }

        struct sk_buff *skb = tp->rx_skbuff[entry];
        if (unlikely(!skb)) {
            printk("Inconsistent Rx chain\n");
            continue;
        }

        prefetch(skb->data - NET_IP_ALIGN);
        tp->rx_skbuff[entry] = NULL;

        skb_put(skb, frame_len);
        dma_unmap_single(tp->device, tp->rx_skbuff_dma[entry],
                         tp->dma_buf_sz, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);

       /* from this point it is safe to access the data of the rx skb. 
          the DMA transaction is already complete
          and the rx buffer is unmapped from the DMA */

        netif_receive_skb(skb);
    }

    rx_refill(dev);

    return count;
}
```

**Prepare the Rx buffers for the next DMA transactions**

```
static inline void rx_refill(struct net_device *dev)
{
    struct my_private *tp = (struct my_private *)dev->priv;
    int dirty = get_num_of_rx_dirty(tp);
    unsigned int entry = tp->dirty_rx;

    while (dirty-- > 0) {
        if (likely(!tp->rx_skbuff[entry])) {
            struct sk_buff *skb;

            skb = netdev_alloc_skb_ip_align(dev, tp->dma_buf_sz);
            if (unlikely(!skb)) {
                printk("fail to alloc skb entry %d\n", entry);
                break;
            }

            rx_q->rx_skbuff[entry] = skb;
            rx_q->rx_skbuff_dma[entry] = dma_map_single(tp->device, skb->data,
                                                        tp->dma_buf_sz, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);       
            if (dma_mapping_error(tp->device, tp->rx_skbuff_dma[entry])) {
                printk("Rx DMA map failed\n");
                dev_kfree_skb(skb);
                break;
            }
        }

        entry = get_rx_entry(entry, DMA_RX_SIZE);
    }

    tp->dirty_rx = entry;
}
```

**Free the Rx Buffers**

```
static void free_rx_buffer(struct net_device *dev, int i)
{
    struct my_private *tp = (struct my_private *)dev->priv;

    if (tp->rx_skbuff[i]) {
        dma_unmap_single(tp->device, tp->rx_skbuff_dma[i],
                         tp->dma_buf_sz, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
        dev_kfree_skb_any(tp->rx_skbuff[i]);
    }
    tp->rx_skbuff[i] = NULL;
}
```